# How can I make such a radio button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show such radiobuttons to user inside of modalbottomsheet.After  selecting one of them and close this modal bottomsheet.Whenever I re open thos modalbottomsheet it should navigate the chosen one with the same animation.How can I do it?For better understanding I attach an image of app that I want to make.[image: I want to do the same one]

here it is a gif [image]

I think I have to write this radiobutton custom.But do not know how to do it

Comment: are you referring `1 2 3 4 5` in model sheet as radiobuuton? if so u can do it just container with border radius

Comment: yeah I mean all numbers.At the same time animation effect.How can I get this animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is my recreating of the design.**

Modify it according to your need

[image: see resukt]

1. It will persist the value of chosen one (i used choice chip to accomplish this)
2. I used to listview.builder to list items (so you can edit how much you want)
3. You can place this bottomsheet on any onTap/onPress event
4. You will get the animation aswell becasause its the default animation of showModalBottomSheet

> CODE:

```
List quantities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];      //declare quantity values 
int _value = 0;                                    //declare selection value



//use it on any onpressed/ontap event

showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(50))),
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                    height: 280,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            'Select Quantity',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: quantities.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                                    child: ChoiceChip(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        selectedShadowColor: Colors.black,
                                        shadowColor: Colors.black,
                                        selectedColor: Colors.white,
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: (_value == index)
                                                ? const Color(0XFF4652F2)
                                                : Colors.black),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            side: (_value == index)
                                                ? const BorderSide(
                                                    width: 5,
                                                    color: Color(0XFF4652F2))
                                                : BorderSide.none,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                                        label: Text(
                                          quantities[index].toString(),
                                        ),
                                        selected: _value == index,
                                        onSelected: (bool selected) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _value = (selected ? index : 0);
                                          });
                                        }),
                                  );
                                }),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 24,
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: const ButtonStyle(
                                  shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(20)))),
                                  padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                      EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 28,
                                          bottom: 28,
                                          left: 54,
                                          right: 54)),
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                      Color(0XFF4652F2))),
                              child: const Text(
                                'Update',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
```

Comment: Thank you sir.However the state does not renew itself.I used setstate it does not work

Comment: you need to declare it inside a statefulwidget to work the state

Comment: it does not work sir.

Comment: welcome. if you got what u expected you can upvote and accept my answer.